# Prevent option from being disabled in the current selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When trying to submit my form, the `guard[]` field doesn't submit because the options in the select fields are disabled on submit.

The code I'm working with disables the option across all selects once chosen, but I'm looking for a way to keep it enabled for the one it was selected with (i.e. if I choose "Dingo" in the first select option in the guard[] name, then the 1st select will have Dingo enabled while the 2nd and 3rd selects will have it disabled.) Code attached below.

I'm either looking for a way to get the element ID from the TagName (as seen in my code comment) or a way to re-enable the disabled option before the form is submitted.

JS/JQ:

```
function disableGuards(selectOption)
{
    var selectedGuards = [];
    var allGuards = document.getElementsByName("guard[]");
    var editedSelect = selectOption.id;

    for (var i = 0; i < allGuards.length; i++)
    {
        selectedGuards.push(allGuards[i].value); 
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < allGuards.length; i++)
    {
        var options = allGuards[i].getElementsByTagName("option");
        for (var o = 1; o < options.length; o++)
        {
            var val = options[o].value;
            var chosen = selectedGuards.indexOf(val);
            var myvalue = allGuards[i].value;

            options[o].disabled = (chosen != -1 && val != (myvalue && "NONE") /*&& editedSelect != a way to get the elementId from TagName*/);
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("guard1").value == "RAND")
    {
        document.getElementById("guard2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("guard3").disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("guard2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("guard3").disabled = ((document.getElementById("guard2").value == "NONE") ? true : false);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard1' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>1st Choice...</option>
<option value='RAND'>No Preferences, Please Assign an Instructor</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard2' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>2nd Choice...</option>
<option value='NONE'>No 2nd Preference</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard3' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>3rd Choice...</option>
<option value='NONE'>No 3rd Preference</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could make the second and third selects dynamic so once first choice is made it populates the second select with the options left, then the third with those options left. is that what you want? If they chose Mike the first time the second and third options shouldn't be Mike

Comment: Did you try using jQuery's .submit() event for this? Bind it to your form and enable the selects inside the event's function

Comment: @EasyBB The way it works now, if I select anything from any field it will disable in the others. So, if I pick "Zach" from the 2nd field, it will disable it in the 1st and 3rd. It also unfortunately disables it in the 2nd field, so I want a way to have it either not disable or re-enable itself on submit. I was looking into the jQuery .submit as lucasnadalutti suggested, but I wasn't able to get it to work properly.

Comment: Try my answer's code and tell me if it worked, as I can't test it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
    return true;
  });
});
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dttmb4hx/).

Comment: That's odd. I will place your code in a fiddle and see if I can find out why.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code actually works with my addition in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dttmb4hx/ (just notice that I changed return true to false in the fiddle's code to prevent the form from submitting so you could see that the options are re-enabled).

Comment: Yeah that's real odd. Must be a problem with where you're placing the script. Please see my updated answer for one last try. :)

Comment: I knew it went within the document.ready service, and instead of having it at the bottom (where i tested it a few minutes ago), I moved it to the top and it seems to be working perfectly. I guess ordering in jQuery makes a difference. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Find all options which are selected, then remove the disabled keyword

#### Vanilla Javascipt

```
document.getElementById("#testform").addEventListener("submit",function (e) {
    var options = e.querySelector("option:checked"), option, i;
    for(i = 0; option = options[i]; i++) {
        option.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}, false);
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#testform").submit(function () {
    $('option:selected', this).removeProp("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you could add a condition: `if(selectOption !== allGuards[i]) { // disable }`, which would leave the option enabled for the select that triggered the handler.

```js
function disableGuards(selectOption)
{
    var allGuards = document.getElementsByName("guard[]");

    for (var i = 0; i < allGuards.length; i++)
    {
        if(allGuards[i] === selectOption) {
          continue;
        }
        var options = allGuards[i].getElementsByTagName("option");
        for (var o = 1; o < options.length; o++)
        {   
            if(options[o].value === selectOption.value) {
              options[o].disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("guard1").value == "RAND")
    {
        document.getElementById("guard2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("guard3").disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("guard2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("guard3").disabled = ((document.getElementById("guard2").value == "NONE") ? true : false);
    }
}
```

```html
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard1' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>1st Choice...</option>
<option value='RAND'>No Preferences, Please Assign an Instructor</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard2' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>2nd Choice...</option>
<option value='NONE'>No 2nd Preference</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='guard[]' style='width:100%' id='guard3' onChange='disableGuards(this)'>
<option selected disabled>3rd Choice...</option>
<option value='NONE'>No 3rd Preference</option>
<option value='Dingo'>Dingo</option>
<option value='Mike'>Mike</option>
<option value='Stephanie'>Stephanie</option>
<option value='Zach'>Zach</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is getting somewhere. Now, when I submit, the last value will be passed, but the other two will be discarded.

ex: If I pick Mark, Stephanie, and Zach (in sliders 1, 2, and 3, respectively) in that order, then "Zach" will be submitted as array value 0 and the other two are discarded as they were disabled.

Comment: Ah. I see. I'll look at it a bit more closely.

Comment: Updated. That work? Drat. I see now that the options don't get re-enabled if you select something else. Hmm.

Comment: Thanks for all you're doing to help. Even if you don't get it, I'm very thankful for people like you and @lucasnadalutti

Comment: @humble.rumble's answer might be the simplest solution.